# Amp mustache get index in C#

Tags: c#, amp-html, amp-mustache

How can I get the index of each item that is rendered with Mustache inside an Amp-list? Here's an example of my html :

```
<amp-list id=""
        layout="fixed-height"
        height="130"
        binding="no"
        items="."
        single-item="."
        src="https://api.myjson.com/bins/6jjqc">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            <amp-carousel carousel-preview"
                 width="auto"
                 height="130"
                 layout="fixed-height"
                 type="carousel">
                     <a on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index={{@index}})" class="dayweek">{{day}}</a>
            </amp-carousel>
       </template>
</amp-list>
```

I have used {{@index}} but since this HTML is rendered inside C#, C# thinks @index is a variable and sends an error

Answer (score 1):

"rendered inside C#" - I assume you mean it is rendered by a Razor View?

In that case you will need to escape your `@` by doubling it, to have Razor output a literal `@` without interpreting it as a variable.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#razor-syntax):

> When an @ symbol is followed by a Razor reserved keyword, it transitions into Razor-specific markup. Otherwise, it transitions into plain C#.
>
> To escape an @ symbol in Razor markup, use a second @ symbol:

```
<p>@@Username</p>
```